# Unrecognized selector crash when getting intValue from NSNumber in CoreData entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, crash

I'm retrieving a entity from my Core Data store and putting it into an array called `fetchedObjects`. I'm trying to get a integer value from an `NSNumber`, but my app is crashing.

Here's the code:

```
 NSNumber *idioma = [fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"idioma"];
```

If a do a `NSLog()` like this:

```
  NSLog(@"idioma = %@", idioma);
```

I get something like this `idioma = ( 0 )`

But if I try call intValue on the `NSNumber` the applications crashes. Here's an example:

```
if ([idioma intValue] > 0 ) {
   //do something
 } else {
   //else do something else
 }
```

Error message and top of the stack trace:

```
2014-04-30 21:50:15.100 Mensagens 2[18797:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f31080'
*** First throw call stack: (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x01b5d1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018dc8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x01bfa243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x01b4d50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x01b4d0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
        5   Mensagens 2                         0x000034fd -[ViewController logMensagem] + 1645
        6   Mensagens 2                         0x00002da0 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 112
        7   UIKit                               0x006bb33d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
        8   UIKit                               0x006bb5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
```

This is how I'm setting the "idioma"

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:lingua]; // lingua is a NSInteger
[entitie setIdioma:number];
```

[image: The Entitie][image: entitie.h]

Comment: 1) Post the complete error. 2) It seems that `idioma` is an array with 1 number, not an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Whatever object is stored in the key @"idioma" probably isn't an `NSNumber`, based on the information in the question.

Comment: idioma is a integer16, that has to be saved as NSNumber

Comment: I suggest posting us how you're storing it.

Comment: NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:lingua]; // Lingua is a NSInteger
    [AnyEntitie setIdioma:number]; // Seta idioma da mensagem

Comment: 1) Put this in the question.  2) Post the actually errors.  3) If you're going to ask questions about your code on SO, I suggest writing your code in English.

Comment: Normally it will tell you the what the unrecognized selector was and the class of the instance it was sent to you. You should post that as it will make answering the question easier

Comment: @Jonathan. It will tell you if it's a class.  Because he has only a memory address, he's trying to send a message to a memory address that doesn't hold an Objective-C object.  It's a big clue.

Comment: Updated the question, with more info, the error can be seeing here http://pastebin.com/x3vqVvhe

Comment: @Jonathan. Err, nevermind, he updated to include the error where it shows the class.

Comment: What is `fetchedObjects`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an NSArray with an NSNumber, but you are trying to access it like it was an NSNumber.  This line:

```
NSNumber *idioma = [fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"idioma"];
```

should be:

```
 NSNumber *idioma = [[fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"idioma"]objectAtIndex:0];
```